# Examples of context menus that don't require a right click

Tags: user-interface, office-2007

I am looking for examples of menus or toolbars that are shown without having to perform a right click.

One example is the mini toolbar in Office 2007 which is shown automatically when selecting text. Are there any other examples out there of menus which are shown on a single click?

[image: Office 2007 mini toolbar]
<sub>(source: [geekpedia.com](http://www.geekpedia.com/pics/Office%202007/MiniToolbar.png))</sub>

I am looking for an elegant way to provide formatting options right on the canvas, next to a shape.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to check on the UI design patterns sites, you'll find some interesting solutions there for sure:

- http://ui-patterns.com/
- http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/index.php
- http://uipatternfactory.com/

Take a look at this floating toolbar too:
http://daersystems.com/jquery/toolbars/

Comment: thanks for the links Ariel. interesting to read although I couldn't find anything that would describe something similar to the mini-toolbar. with the one exception of the radial menu on the uipatternfactory site.

Answer (score 1):

This is something my colleague has been developing for a mind-map, of sorts.
Click the >> arrows on the node to bring out the menu (displays 2 options), click down arrow for more options relating to that item. The black triangle on the left is a handle for dragging the node.

[mindmap menu http://nightmareboutique.com/junk/menu.gif](http://nightmareboutique.com/junk/menu.gif)

Answer (score 0):

on ZoneAlarm, the program control, you can click a program to set it's values with a left click.